# How to build and deploy SSRS project through VSTS?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, ssrs-2014

I created simple SSRS project in VS2015. I want to build and deploy the SSRS project using VSTS by creating the build definition and release definition steps.

Is there any third party VSTS extension available or for SSRS build and SSRS Deploy not same like as SSIS Build and SSIS Deploy tasks?

Can you please tell me how to build and deploy SSRS project through VSTS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [SQL Server Reporting Services Deployment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tobania.SqlReportingServices) extension.

Simple sample tasks:

1. Command Line (Tool: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`; Arguments: `"$(build.sourcesdirectory)/ReportDemo.sln" /build "$(BuildConfiguration)"`; Working folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)`)
2. SQL Server Reports Deployment (Report files: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/*.rdl`; Upload path:`/BuildTest`; Webservice URL: `http://XXX/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl`)

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me how to build the SSRS project in VSTS?

Comment: I faced the issue as "  ##[error]System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information." during SSRS Deployment in release definition.

Comment: @pradeep Add System.Debug variable and set it to true, then start a release and share the log on the OneDrive.

Comment: This is link for logs: https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-JUB9_wu9CvW39Nwtyauj-NaM3

Comment: @pradeep The Webservice URL is incorrect, try to append ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl to the reportserver URL (I am using http://XXX/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl), Related article: [Report Server Web Service Endpoints](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155398(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: @pradeep To build the report project, you need to call devenv.exe. [Command Line Support for SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/reporting-services-in-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt#bkmk_CommandLineSupportForssdt). If it throws definition schema issue, you can upload/deploy the built report files that in bin\debug/replease folder. (I updated my answer)

Comment: After updating web service URL, its working fine but I am little bit confusing to give Root path on SSRS in the SqlReportingServicesDeployment task.

Comment: @pradeep It is the folder path per to root, for example, go to http ://xxx/Reports, there is BuildTest folder, so I specify /BuildTest in upload path, then the report will be deployed to the BuildTest folder.

Comment: Thanks @Starain, you helped a lot for me regarding the SSRS deployment issues.

Comment: I created the folder manually in my server to deploy reports into it. but I faced some issues, please feel free to see my logs https://1drv.ms/u/s!At-JUB9_wu9CvW6dtNl_Gjqzl0pQ

Comment: Currently I used SqlReportingServicesFolderDeployment task. I didn't see any BuildTest folder in my reporting server.

Comment: Do you have white space in the folder name? (/SSRS Using Folder Structure)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153585/discussion-between-starain-msft-and-pradeep).

Comment: Currently MSBuild is able to build rptproj just fine (build log shows that rdl files succeeded, but I don't see any build output in artifacts `drop` folder of TFS. And also I'm not sure how do I run the step 2. in my deploy process separately from the build process.